# C# GridView with GridViewItems

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps

Hee Guys,

I'm used to program for android but for school I have to program an application in C#, however I'm stuck on the following issue.

The project is a Windows Store project. However I get some info about movies from an API, I want to show these movies in a GridView. Currently I'm adding al these movies manually (20) and then show them. Now if I click them I want to retrieve the current ID from that item, however I have no clue how to pass on this ID.

Is there a easy way to do so? And is there an easier way then to add the items manually?

Example of what I have:

```
<GridView SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True"  Foreground="#DEFFFFFF">
    <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_1" >
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
            <Image Name="image1" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock Name="title1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </Grid>
    </GridViewItem>
    <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_1">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
            <Image Name="image2" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock Name="title2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </Grid>
    </GridViewItem>
    <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_1">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
            <Image Name="image3" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock Name="title3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/> 
        </Grid>
    </GridViewItem>
</GridView>
```

I have 20 of these each and I add them all manually. So is there an easier way and how do I pass an ID in these items for onClick purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Make an event for the SelectionOnChanged trigger helped.

```
 private void GridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView) sender;
        int index = grid.SelectedIndex;
}
```

This way I get the index and get the desired values from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using ItemClick event.

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);
}
```